# Prepare SQL statements and enter only if not duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I am creating a Sales Order form for the small business I work for. I have a form that connects to a database for drop-down menus and then text boxes to add new data if needed. There are four more sections that can appear if all data boxes are filled in in the section prior.

The inputs that link to the database include `Company`, `Customer`, `Tool` and `Part` And then there is a `Description` to enter on work to be done. So once `Tool`, `Part`, and `Description` have been filled in, a second section with another `Tool`, `Part`, and `Description` come into view. I have a script I have called Update.php that determines what fields have been filled and thus what to enter into the database. What I have been trying to do is to avoid duplicate entries. So if on the first section a `UpdateNewTool` has been inputted and then on the second section that is put into that field again to associate another `Part` with it, that data will be inserted twice. How can I go about throwing out one of those input statements?

My update.php code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "Sales_Orders";

$UpdateCompany=$_POST['UpdateCompany'];
$UpdateNewCompany=$_POST['UpdateNewCompany'];

$UpdateCustomer=$_POST['UpdateCustomer'];
$UpdateNewCustomer=$_POST['UpdateNewCustomer'];

$UpdateTool=$_POST['UpdateTool'];
$UpdateTool2=$_POST['UpdateTool2'];
$UpdateTool3=$_POST['UpdateTool3'];
$UpdateTool4=$_POST['UpdateTool4'];

$UpdateNewTool=$_POST['UpdateNewTool'];
$UpdateNewTool2=$_POST['UpdateNewTool2'];
$UpdateNewTool3=$_POST['UpdateNewTool3'];
$UpdateNewTool4=$_POST['UpdateNewTool4'];

$UpdateNewPart=$_POST['UpdateNewPart'];
$UpdateNewPart2=$_POST['UpdateNewPart2'];
$UpdateNewPart3=$_POST['UpdateNewPart3'];
$UpdateNewPart4=$_POST['UpdateNewPart4'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$data = [];


// BEGIN CONDITIONAL STATEMENTS



// New Company added by itself
if (!empty($UpdateNewCompany)) {
    $data[] = [ '1', $UpdateNewCompany, $UpdateNewCompany, NULL ];
    $data[] = [ '2', '', '', $UpdateNewCompany ];
    $data[] = [ '3', '', '', $UpdateNewCompany ];
}

//Using the Company Drop-down box
if (!empty($UpdateCompany)) {
    $UpdateNewCompany = $UpdateCompany; // If there is no new company inserted, $UpdateNewCompany becomes $UpdateCompany

    if (!empty($UpdateNewCustomer)) {
        $data[] = [ '2', $UpdateNewCustomer, $UpdateNewCustomer, $UpdateNewCompany ];
    }



    if (empty($UpdateTool)) { //If there is a new tool to add

        if (!empty($UpdateNewTool)) {
            $data[] = [ '3', $UpdateNewTool, $UpdateNewTool, $UpdateNewCompany ];
            $data[] = [ '4', '', '', $UpdateNewTool ];
        }
        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart, $UpdateNewPart, $UpdateNewTool ];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($UpdateTool)) { // If there is no new tool to add
        $UpdateNewTool = $UpdateTool;

        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart, $UpdateNewPart, $UpdateNewTool ];
        }
    }

//Part 2
    if (empty($UpdateTool2)) { //If there is a new tool to add

        if (!empty($UpdateNewTool2)) {
            $data[] = [ '3', $UpdateNewTool2, $UpdateNewTool2, $UpdateNewCompany ];
            $data[] = [ '4', '', '', $UpdateNewTool2 ];
        }
        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart2)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart2, $UpdateNewPart2, $UpdateNewTool2 ];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($UpdateTool2)) { // If there is no new tool to add
        $UpdateNewTool2 = $UpdateTool2;

        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart2)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart2, $UpdateNewPart2, $UpdateNewTool2 ];
        }
    }

//Part 3
    if (empty($UpdateTool3)) { //If there is a new tool to add

        if (!empty($UpdateNewTool3)) {
            $data[] = [ '3', $UpdateNewTool3, $UpdateNewTool3, $UpdateNewCompany ];
            $data[] = [ '4', '', '', $UpdateNewTool3 ];
        }
        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart3)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart3, $UpdateNewPart3, $UpdateNewTool3 ];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($UpdateTool3)) { // If there is no new tool to add
        $UpdateNewTool3 = $UpdateTool3;

        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart3)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart3, $UpdateNewPart3, $UpdateNewTool3 ];
        }
    }

//Part 4
    if (empty($UpdateTool4)) { //If there is a new tool to add

        if (!empty($UpdateNewTool4)) {
            $data[] = [ '3', $UpdateNewTool4, $UpdateNewTool4, $UpdateNewCompany ];
            $data[] = [ '4', '', '', $UpdateNewTool4 ];
        }
        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart4)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart4, $UpdateNewPart4, $UpdateNewTool4 ];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($UpdateTool4)) { // If there is no new tool to add
        $UpdateNewTool4 = $UpdateTool4;

        if (!empty($UpdateNewPart4)) {
            $data[] = [ '4', $UpdateNewPart4, $UpdateNewPart4, $UpdateNewTool4 ];
        }
    }
}

$insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Sales_Orders_dynlist_items (listid,name,value,parent) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?)");
if ( $insert === false )    {
    echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    die;
}

foreach ( $data as $item ){
    if ( $insert->bind_param("ssss", ...$item) === false )    {
        echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    }
    if ( $insert->execute() === false )    {
        echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    }
}




$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm pretty sure the place that needs work will be:

```
foreach ( $data as $item ){
    if ( $insert->bind_param("ssss", ...$item) === false )    {
        echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    }
    if ( $insert->execute() === false )    {
        echo "Error:".$conn->error;
    }
}
```

So for instance, sometimes we will need different parts with the same tool number. Therefore, if the user puts in a new job number such as "1234" and Part "abcd" then a description as to what's done. Then in the next section, "1234" isn't in the dropbox yet as it hasn't been added to the database yet. So the user puts "1234" in the tool again but "dcba" as the part and another description. Once submitted there will be two entries in the database with `['3', '1234', '1234', 'Whatever Company'];`

Thanks for any input!

Comment: I would have thought this was best dealt with at the web page level.  Report the error when the user tries to submit the info rather than kick it out when you try and put it on the database.

Comment: That would work, but it might not be an error. Sometimes we will need different parts with the same tool number. Therefore, if we have a new job number that has been added such as "1234" and Part "abcd" then a description as to what's done. Then in the next section, "1234" isn't in the dropbox yet as it isn't in the database yet. So the user puts "1234" in the tool again but "dcba" as the part and another description. Once submitted there will be two entries in the database with `['3', '1234', '1234', 'Whatever Company' ];` @NigelRen

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry for the confusion. I added clarification on that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to take a different approach at this. What I ended up doing was set up a javascript script that determined if the NewTool input box was empty and if not, add that input value as an option to the Tool2 and so on boxes. The javascript is as follows:

```
function addOpTool() {
    if(document.getElementById('NewTool').value != '') {
        var x = document.getElementById("Tool2");
        var y = document.getElementById("Tool3");
        var z = document.getElementById("Tool4");
        var test = document.getElementById("NewTool");
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        var option3 = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = test.value;
        option2.text = test.value;
        option3.text = test.value;
        x.add(option);
        y.add(option2);
        z.add(option3);
        }
}

function addOpTool2() {
    if(document.getElementById('NewTool2').value != '') {
        var y = document.getElementById("Tool3");
        var z = document.getElementById("Tool4");
        var test = document.getElementById("NewTool2");
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        var option3 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.text = test.value;
        option3.text = test.value;
        y.add(option2);
        z.add(option3);
        }
}

function addOpTool3() {
    if(document.getElementById('NewTool3').value != '') {
        var z = document.getElementById("Tool4");
        var test = document.getElementById("NewTool3");
        var option3 = document.createElement("option");
        option3.text = test.value;
        z.add(option3);
        }
}
```

I added these functions to the appropriate `onchange` of `NewTool`, `NewTool2`, and `NewTool3`.

So for instance the user inputs "1234" in `NewTool` and "LH-Side" in `NewPart`. Then in the following form section there is now an option of "1234" in the `Tool2` dropdown box and the user can just select that and then input "RH-Side" in `NewPart2`.

When submitting the form, only ONE instance of the tool# "1234" will be put into the database, solving the problem I was running into!